# Why does Contours plugin crash QGIS 2.18?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, contour, qgis-2.18

I am running QGIS 2.18 on a mac and trying to use the Contours plugin. I've never had problems with it before but then I updated QGIS using Kyngchaos.  Now Contours crashes QGIS when I choice "Filled Contours" or "Both".  It works fine for generating just contour lines.  When it crashes, it doesn't throw up an error window; the whole program just quits.

I tried stepping back to an older version of QGIS but that not only didn't solve the problem, it also created a host of other issues. I've also uninstalled and reinstalled the plugin.

How can I get Contours plugin fully functional again?

Comment: not sur it's help but according to https://github.com/ccrook/QGIS-Contour-Plugin/issues/18 can you try to install `python-matplotlib-qt4` ?

Comment: I'm over my head here.  Is `python-matplotlib-qt4` a tool within matplotlib?  I have matplotlib installed and QGIS finds it fine through the python console.

Comment: Don't know much about matpotlib, and it could not resolve your issue. The contours are written to a memory (scratch) layer. If the
MemoryLayerSaver plugin is installed these are saved with the
QGIS project. Otherwise they can be saved to another persistant
format. Did you installed MemoryLayerSaver ?

Comment: did you try with a sample of your data ?